# How can I disable Responsiveness on IE 8 using the Modernizr & Respond.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, modernizr, respond.js

I am building an app using Modernizr, Respond.js, Bootstrap and custom css coded using some media queries as well. I want to disable the responsiveness on IE8 (Any media queries under 1024px). Is there anyway I can disable all or selected media queries on IE8, because the style is messed up when the browser is resized, so I want to have the regular desktop view only supported on IE8. I was able to disable the Bootstrap styles by the instructions at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive but I don't know where to start to disable all the other media queries. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are ways to make IE use a different set of CSS files: IE conditional comments (work for IE 8 as well). http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to write more codes, I just want to disable the additional css styles that come into effect when resizing the IE8 browser. That way I can stick with the normal desktop IE styles.

Comment: Right, so stick all the relevant CSS into a separate file, and use conditional comments to prevent IE from including that file. No additional CSS needed.

Comment: Mmm good idea Thanks. Just going to stick around to see if there are any alternative solution that could be done using Modernizr or Respond.JS and if not then going to apply this solution as this is tedious since there are lots of moving required.

Comment: Respond.js is a polyfill for media queries for IE8. So if you don't want media queries in IE8, then just don't use respond.js. Seems simple to me?

Comment: @Spudley everything is not so simple, of course we can turn off respond.js but some styles could be written in media queries for desktop as well and other dependencies possible. But your suggestion is most good thing i know now. Still finding simpler/better way )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way to just deliver the desktop version to IE8 when using BS3 which is mobile first. I did not want to use RespondJS (there is a flicker plus I don't care to provide/deal with anything but one size for the IE8 crowd). I ended up using a gulp/grunt task to extract the relevent media queries for desktop and add them to a separate file to be added with IE conditional statement.

There is a node library called [node-match-media](https://github.com/mstrutt/node-match-media) that will do the trick. Additionally there is a [Grunt plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-match-media).

There was no Gulp plugin but it was easy enough to whip up a task. In my case I only have one css file to parse for media queries - adjust as needed.

```
var tap = require('gulp-tap');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('desktopify', function() {
  var matchMedia = require('node-match-media');
  matchMedia.configure({
    width: '992px', // Pretend width to force
    height: '768px', // Pretend height to force
    px_em_ratio: 16,
    always_match: []
  });
  // My original css for modern browsers
  gulp.src('./public/styles/public.css')
    .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
      file.contents = new Buffer(matchMedia.run(file.contents.toString()));
    }))
    // Create a custom file that contains just the needed media queries
    .pipe(rename('ie8.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles'));
});
```

Then in my html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/ie8.css">    
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi, I think I'm slightly outside your target audience. Are you able to give an example of what this code did, or your final file on a recent bootstrap file?